# Setting NFS Path on java/spring-boot system

Tags: java, spring-boot, openshift, redhat

I want to show or download the following txt file on system developed in Java/Spring Boot:

[image: File that i want to show or download]

The code that i am using to upload the files in the system on the nfs server is this:

```
public static String uploadFileVNP = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/Dev/nfs/sopptFiles/VNP";
    
    @PostMapping("/process_svnp")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('MSA_USER', 'MSA_USER_ADMINISTRATIVE', 'MSA_MODERATOR', 'ADMIN')")
    public String msSoppProcesoRegistroVNP(SVNP svnp, String date, String id, String date_ic, String date_fc, @RequestParam("fileVNP") MultipartFile[] fileVNP) {
        
        if(svnpRepository.existsRecordSVNP(date, id, date_ic, date_fc)) {
            return "redirect:/msa?filter=home?error";           
        }
        
        StringBuilder fileNames = new StringBuilder();
        for(MultipartFile file : fileVNP) {
            Path fileNameAndPath = Paths.get(uploadFileVNP, file.getOriginalFilename());
            fileNames.append(file.getOriginalFilename());
            try {
                Files.write(fileNameAndPath, file.getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        svnpService.registerSVNP(svnp);
        return "redirect:/msa?filter=Home?success";
        
    }
```

The code that i am using to list the uploaded files on the nfs is this:

```
$("#refFileVacTarget").text(svnp.refFileVac);
let link="/VNP/" + svnp.refFileVac;
$('#refFileVacTarget').attr('href', link);
```

It is important to aim that this code works in the local server, but when i deploy on git repository it doesn´t work anymore.

With all this information there are three precise questions.

1.How can i access to the redhat nfs path from the system? (/Dev/nfs/sopptFiles/)

2.How can i set the path to get or upload files?

Comment: do you get any exception ? like file access or access denied ?